# Firebase UI RecyclerView does not display data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

There are a lot questions related to this but they did not help me solve the problem. The code runs successfully and displays no errors. What is wrong with this code?

```
public class JobsList extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions options;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    private EditText search_text;
    private ImageButton search_btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jobs_list);

    search_text = findViewById(R.id.search_text);
    search_btn = findViewById(R.id.search_btn);


    search_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String search_txt = search_text.getText().toString();
            if (search_txt.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(JobsList.this, "Please enter search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                search_text.requestFocus();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(JobsList.this, SearchResults.class);
                intent.putExtra("search_query", search_text.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });


    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Jobs");
```

This is the code for FirebaseRecyclerOptions & FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

```
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Jobs>()
            .setQuery(databaseReference, Jobs.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Jobs, JobView>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final JobView holder, int i, @NonNull Jobs j) {
            holder.title.setText(j.getTitle());
            holder.salary = j.getSalary();
            holder.company.setText(j.getCompany());
            holder.deadline.setText(j.getDeadline());
            holder.location.setText(j.getLocation());
            holder.desc = j.getDescription();

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("Title", (String) holder.title.getText());
                    extras.putString("Salary", holder.salary);
                    extras.putString("Location", (String) holder.location.getText());
                    extras.putString("Desc", holder.desc);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), JobDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }



        @NonNull
        @Override
        public JobView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.jobs_row, parent, false);
            return new JobView(v);
        }
    };
    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);





}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (adapter != null)
    adapter.startListening();
}
public static class JobView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView title,company,deadline;
    public String salary;
    public TextView location;
    public String desc;
    public JobView(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Jtitle);
        location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.JLocation);
        company = itemView.findViewById(R.id.company);
        deadline = itemView.findViewById(R.id.JDeadline);
       }
   }

}
```

And here is the code for my Jobs model class
    package com.example.jobs;

```
public class Jobs {
private  String Title,Salary, Location, Description,Company,Deadline;

public Jobs() {
}


public Jobs(String title, String salary, String location, String description, String company, String deadline) {
    Title = title;
    Salary = salary;
    Location = location;
    Description = description;
    Company = company;
    Deadline = deadline;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}

public String getSalary() {
    return Salary;
}

public void setSalary(String salary) {
    Salary = salary;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return Location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    Location = location;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}


public String getCompany() {
    return Company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
    Company = company;
}

public String getDeadline() {
    return Deadline;
}

public void setDeadline(String deadline) {
    Deadline = deadline;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you share us your database?

Comment: @Ticherhaz Sure. I add image link

Comment: Try to set the LinearLayoutManager. `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));`

Comment: Thank you, but I am already using that in my code.

Comment: how about Rules? have you check it?

Comment: Yes. Read & Write are set to true.

Comment: have you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

there are few things that you have missed in your code.
1. The data you have shown consist in format of,
a. Array of " jobs ".
b. Each Object has a name consider starts with LI.....
c. Then every object has some data with **k:v** pair.

2. I don't see you have **parsed it** before adapter initialization.
3. I didn't found an " **arraylist** " of  that assigned to an adapter.
4. Recycler view requires a layout manager that requires parameters like context, RecyclerView.Vertical,false.
5. Make these changes and then reply.
   Hope it helps.